# Android Service getSharedPreferences Problems

Tags: android, service, sharedpreferences

So basically, my service displays a notification which can be turned off if the user wishes.

The setting is controlled from within the application and is set through a PreferenceActivity.

When exiting the activity:

```
public void onDestroy(){
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    debug.postLog(Log.DEBUG, "Settings", "("+this.toString()+") showNotification: " + prefs.getBoolean("showNotification", true));
```

Shows the correct value, if the user unchecks the checkbox, it shows false and vice versa.

Meanwhile, when I call this at any time in my service:

```
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    Boolean show = prefs.getBoolean("showNotification", true);
    debug.postLog(Log.DEBUG, "Passive Service", "("+this.toString()+") showNotification: " + prefs.getBoolean("showNotification", true));       
    if(prefs.getBoolean("showNotification", true)){
```

I get the same result until the app is fully stopped then restarted, then the current value is kept. It is almost like the service gets a snapshot of the preferences.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, the service was running as remote.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. I was getting quite worried about this one. I just had to delete `android:process=":remote"`